# purpose of specifying bytes when reading text file with different encoding format

Tags: java

I have some questions about specifying numbers of bytes when reading a file with different encoding format.

I have a text file like this:

[image]

and I have a code like this:

```
public static String read(File file) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);

    // How many bytes are fetched at a time
    byte[] bytes = new byte[92]; /// what number to specify inside the byte[ ] here? 
                                // does it have to equal the "size" of the file?
                                // so it is 92 when my text file is 92 bytes?
                               // and it will be 52 if my text file is 52 bytes?
    // An array of bytes used to receive reads
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    // Read the length of byte array. If it is - 1, it means there is no data
    int length = 0;
    // Cycle data
    while ((length = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        // Converts the read to a string
        sb.append(new String(bytes,"UTF-16le" )); // I think specifying number of bytes 
                                                  // affect this line here right? but what
                                     //specifically does it affect String(bytes, "UTF-16le")
    }
    // Close stream
    in.close();
    }

    return sb.toString();
```

The thing I don't understand is what does the code  byte[] bytes = new byte[92] do exactly in this piece of code? the number inside byte [ ], what does it do? I tried various number when I saved my text file in various encoding format. For example, if I save my text file using UTF-16le encoding, my file size is 92 bytes. So if I don't specify 92 there, then my IDE doesn't display those characters inside the text file properly. So say I specify 32, then I got this (which has the extra space and an "b" character at the end now):

[image]

and if I specify 77, I got this:

[image]

so it is not displaying properly.

Also if I saved my text file using UTF-8 encoding, and the size of the file is now 59 bytes. And if I specify 59 in the code, then the characters will be displayed properly. But other number, it won't. So may I know what does setting the sizes of the bytes array do here? does it have to equal to the size (bytes) of the text file where the characters are located in?

Could someone kindly explain in details what setting the size of number of bytes in here do?

```
sb.append(new String(bytes,"UTF-16le" ))
```

Comment: Do you understand what UTF-16 means? That is, how the bytes are translated to Unicode characters?

Comment: It's not exactly an answer to your question, but reading Unicode text files as bytes is not as straightforward as it might seem. It's easy to introduce data corruption this way, if the bytes you read do not correctly align with character boundaries. Better to wrap your `FileInputStream` with a `FileReader`, which can automatically translate bytes to characters using a standard encoding you specify in the constructor. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`byte[] bytes = new byte[92]` means reserve me 92 bytes of space to put raw data in. NOTE the difference between bytes and characters(which may be multiple bytes).

`length = in.read(bytes)` reads bytes until no more are available or the buffer `bytes` is full. You should be looking at your `length` variable returned to determine how many bytes are read and append only those bytes to the string buffer.

`sb.append(new String(bytes,"UTF-16le" ))` attempts to decode **all** bytes in the `bytes` buffer using the specified character encoding scheme. This includes any bytes in the buffer that exist past the length of the last read which is the source of your extra characters.

Comment: Thanks I think I understood more now.